The meaning of "have equal distribution" and why that yields the inequality ( or equality).
Let $X$ be a Banach space on $\mathbb C$, $1\leqq p<\infty$, and $c_1,\cdots,c_n\in \{-1,1\}$, $x_1,\cdots x_n\in X.$
And let $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be a sequence of $\mathbb R$-valued random variables on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ such that $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is independent and each $r_k$ is uniformly distributed over $\{-1,1\}.$
Then, I want to know why we have
$$\displaystyle \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n c_k r_k x_k\right\|_p=  \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n  r_kx_k\right\|_p.\cdots(\ast)$$
What I know is : Since each $r_k$ is uniformly distributed on $\{-1,1\}$, we have $P(r_k=1)=P(r_k=-1)=1/2$, and independence of $\{r_k\}_k$ yields $\displaystyle P(\bigcap_{k=1}^n \{r_k\in B_k\})=\Pi_{k=1}^n P(\{r_k\in B_k\})$ for Borel sets $B_k.$
My book says that the sequences $\{c_k r_k\}_k$ and $\{r_k\}_k$ have equal disribution and thus $(\ast)$ follows, but I have difficulty in understanding this.
My questions are :
・What is the meaning(definition) of "have equal distribution" ? I haven't find it.
・Why can we say $\{c_k r_k\}_k$ and $\{r_k\}_k$ have equal disribution ?
・How do we derive $\displaystyle \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n c_k r_k x_k\right\|_p=  \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n  r_kx_k\right\|_p$ ?

What is $t$?  Please don't answer ion a comment;i stead.edit your question to include what you mean by $t$ in your question.  You can edit your question but clicking on the Editlink that appears below your question.

To answer your first question: Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have equal distribution if and only if $\mathbb{P}_X = \mathbb{P}_Y$, where $\mathbb{P}_X$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y$ denote their respective distributions, i.e. $\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$, where $A$ is a Borel-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
With this definition in mind, we can answer the second question: Since $r_k \in \{-1,1\}$ almost surely and $c_k \in \{-1,1\}$, we have $c_kr_k \in \{-1,1\}$ almost surely. If $c_k = 1$, we just have $c_kr_k = r_k$, so their distributions must be equal as well. For $c_k = -1$, we have $$\mathbb{P}_{c_kr_k}(\{1\}) = \mathbb{P}(c_kr_k = 1) = \mathbb{P}(r_k = -1) = \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(r_k = 1) = \mathbb{P}_{r_k}(\{1\}),$$ and similarly $\mathbb{P}_{c_kr_k}(\{-1\}) = \mathbb{P}_{r_k}(\{-1\})$. Simply put, since $r_k$ is uniformly distributed over $\{-1,1\}$, $c_kr_k = r_k$ is also uniformly distributed over $\{-1,1\}$ for $c_k \in \{-1,1\}$ since $c_k$ either just flips the two values (if $c_k = -1$) or changes nothing about $r_k$ (if $c_k = 1$).
The third question is best answered in a more general setting: Let $X, \ Y$ be two random variables with equal distributions. Then, for any $p \in [1,\infty)$, by the transformation lemma for pushforward measures (the distribution of a random variable is just a pushforward measure), we have $$\|X\|_p^p = \int_\Omega |X|^p d\mathbb{P} = \int_\mathbb{R} |x|^p d\mathbb{P}_X(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} |y|^p d\mathbb{P}_Y(y) = \int_\Omega |Y|^p d\mathbb{P} = \|Y\|_p^p,$$
where we used that $\mathbb{P}_X = \mathbb{P}_Y$. Thus, $X$ and $Y$ have equal $p$-norms. Since $c_kr_k = r_k$ in distribution and $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is iid, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^n c_kr_k = \sum_{k=1}^n r_k$ in distribution. Applying our lemma from above, we get that $\|\sum_{k=1}^n c_kr_k\|_p = \|\sum_{k=1}^n r_k\|_p$, which should hopefully answer your last question.

Do "$X$ and $Y$ have equal distribution" and "$X=Y$ in distribution" have the same meaning ?

@da Yes, it's just somewhat more concise.

Sorry for the question to the post of a long time ago. In the last part , we have $c_kr_k\underset{d}= r_k$ and ${r_k}{k=1}^n$ is iid, but why this guarantees $\sum{k=1}^n c_k r_k\underset d =\sum_{k=1}^n r_k$ ?

@ZZz Well, it's just sort of replacing each random variable. Since ${r_k}{k=1}^n$ is iid, the distribution of the sum of all of these variables is uniquely determined by the distributions of the $r_k$ (it's their convolution). But since $r_k$ and $c_kr_k$ have the same distribution, ${c_kr_k}{k=1}^n$ is iid as well, so the same logic applies to the distribution of their sum.
